# NodeJS - Global define 'require' scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

Bit of an odd question, so hopefully the simple examples will do the trick as how I plan on using it is a bit complicated to explain for myself.

I am importing my own modules in to my routes.coffee for an Express server. I'd like to require FS just once, in routes.coffee, and have it apply to all imported modules so those scripts can access it too.

For example, **my routes.coffee:**

```
fs = require("fs")
a = require("./a")

module.exports = (app) ->
    app.get '/', (req, res) ->
        a req, res
```

And then a.coffee looks like this:

```
module.exports = (req, res) ->
    cConf = JSON.parse (fs.readFileSync 'data.json', {encoding: 'utf8'})
    res.send cConf
```

In a.coffee, fs is not required at the top of the file so at the moment it won't work, but is defined in routes.coffee. I'd like to just import fs just once in routes.coffee and apply it to all. How could I go about that properly?

Again, question is a bit odd, but how I plan on using it will definitely help with the overall performance of what I have planned. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @alex is right, dont use globals. Makes your code harder to understand down the road. Also don't use anything sync in a route!

You can always require a bunch of stuff quickly `[ fs, http ] = [ 'fs', 'http' ].map(require)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `global.fs = require 'fs'`

that said, don't do that, because it is no good reason to pollute global namespace

Comment: there are plenty of good reasons to "pollute global namespace". Unlike the browser environment, the node coder should have complete control over the scripts running on the machine, so strict cross-compat is not needed, advantageous, or even particularly desirable...

Comment: Yeah, right, "lots of good reasons" to use globals... like not giving a damn about design.